# How to mock (MOQ) IConfidentialClientApplication which has sealed setup AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, azure-ad-msal

I'm getting the following exception when trying to setup the **moq** for an `IConfidentialClientApplication`:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ... =>
> ....ExecuteAsync() Non-overridable members (here:
> AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder.ExecuteAsync)
> may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

```
private Mock<IConfidentialClientApplication> _appMock = new Mock<IConfidentialClientApplication>();

[Fact]
public async Task GetAccessTokenResultAsync_WithGoodSetup_ReturnsToken()
{
    // Leverages MSAL AuthenticationResult constructor meant for mocks in test
    var authentication = CreateAuthenticationResult();

    // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
    _appMock.Setup(_ => _.AcquireTokenForClient(It.IsAny<string[]>()).ExecuteAsync())
        .ReturnsAsync(authentication);

    ... rest of test ...
}
```

An `AcquireTokenForClientParameterBuilder` is returned by `_.AcquireTokenForClient`; "a builder enabling you to add optional parameters before executing the token request". [This is a `sealed` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.acquiretokenforclientparameterbuilder?view=azure-dotnet), so I can't easily mock this tricky object.

---

For those curious, `CreateAuthenticationResult()` is a method that invokes a signature from `Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult` that was specifically added in by Microsoft for stubbing an `AuthenticationResult`, as it cannot be mocked since it too is a sealed class.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/682

Comment: Can you include the definition of the type that is returned from `AcquireTokenForClient()`? It seems that you need to create a separate mock/stub for that type, and have that return the authentication from `ExecuteAsync()`

Comment: @devNull `AcquireTokenForClient()` returns `AcquireTokenForClientParameterBuilder`. I updated to my answer to explain that better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seeing that `AcquireTokenForClientParameterBuilder` is provided through an external library, you obviously aren't able to modify it to be more testable. Given that, I'd suggest abstracting that code behind your own interface (kind of applying the Adapter pattern for testing purposes).

Take the following service/test as an example of how you'd currently be using the `IConfidentialClientApplication` and trying to mock it (which results in the same error you're seeing):

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _confidentialClientApplication;

    public MyService(IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication)
    {
        _confidentialClientApplication = confidentialClientApplication;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(IEnumerable<string> scopes)
    {
        AcquireTokenForClientParameterBuilder tokenBuilder = _confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes);
        AuthenticationResult token = await tokenBuilder.ExecuteAsync();
        return token.AccessToken;
    }
}

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        Mock<IConfidentialClientApplication> _appMock = new Mock<IConfidentialClientApplication>();
        AuthenticationResult authentication = CreateAuthenticationResult("myToken");
        _appMock
            .Setup(_ => _.AcquireTokenForClient(It.IsAny<string[]>()).ExecuteAsync())
            .ReturnsAsync(authentication);

        var myService = new MyService(_appMock.Object);
        string accessToken = await myService.GetAccessToken(new string[] { });

        Assert.Equal("myToken", accessToken);
    }

    private AuthenticationResult CreateAuthenticationResult(string accessToken) => 
        new AuthenticationResult(accessToken, true, null, DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now, string.Empty, null, null, null, Guid.Empty);
}
```

By introducing a separate interface your code can the simply depend on that, putting you in control of how it will be used/tested:

```
public interface IIdentityClientAdapter
{
    Task<string> GetAccessToken(IEnumerable<string> scopes);
}

public class IdentityClientAdapter : IIdentityClientAdapter
{
    private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _confidentialClientApplication;

    public IdentityClientAdapter(IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication)
    {
        _confidentialClientApplication = confidentialClientApplication;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(IEnumerable<string> scopes)
    {
        AcquireTokenForClientParameterBuilder tokenBuilder = _confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes);
        AuthenticationResult token = await tokenBuilder.ExecuteAsync();
        return token.AccessToken;
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    private readonly IIdentityClientAdapter _identityClientAdapter;

    public MyService(IIdentityClientAdapter identityClientAdapter)
    {
        _identityClientAdapter = identityClientAdapter;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(IEnumerable<string> scopes)
    {
        return await _identityClientAdapter.GetAccessToken(scopes);
    }
}

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        Mock<IIdentityClientAdapter> _appMock = new Mock<IIdentityClientAdapter>();
        _appMock
            .Setup(_ => _.GetAccessToken(It.IsAny<string[]>()))
            .ReturnsAsync("myToken");

        var myService = new MyService(_appMock.Object);
        string accessToken = await myService.GetAccessToken(new string[] { });

        Assert.Equal("myToken", accessToken);
    }
}
```

This example is obviously trivialized, but should still apply. The interface would just need to be fit to your needs.

Comment: _appMock.Setup(_ => _.AcquireTokenForClient(It.IsAny<string[]>()).ExecuteAsync()); does not work - Non-overridable members may not be used in setup expressions.

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to fake the response of the `IConfidentialClientApplication` `AcquireTokenForClient` method by faking the `HttpClient` `SendAsync` method.

I had a unit testing requirement as two systems get authentication tokens based on flag status.

So if we see AcquireTokenForClient, it makes two calls: a discovery call (GET) to get the details first, then the actual token call (POST), so to fake this, we have to fake both of these calls.

Let's consider the below implementation for this testing

```
public class TokenService
{
    private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _confidentialClientApplication;

    public TokenService(IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication)
    {
        _confidentialClientApplication = confidentialClientApplication;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetToken(string[] scope)
    {
        var token = await _confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scope).ExecuteAsync();

        return token.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

Here is the class that implements DelegatingHandler, which will help us to fake the HTTP Response. An explanation for this is available at: [How to mock HttpClient/Api call response](https://medium.com/@haiarunghosh/mocking-httpclent-in-unit-tests-c-3089be321f8d)

```
internal class FakeHttpResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Uri, HttpResponseMessage> fakeServiceResponse;
    public FakeHttpResponseHandler()
    {
        fakeServiceResponse = new Dictionary<Uri, HttpResponseMessage>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for adding fake httpResponseMessage for the httpClient operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TQueryStringParameter"> query string parameter </typeparam>
    /// <param name="uri">Service end point URL.</param>
    /// <param name="httpResponseMessage"> Response expected when the service called.</param>
    public void AddFakeServiceResponse(Uri uri, HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        fakeServiceResponse.Remove(uri);
        fakeServiceResponse.Add(uri, httpResponseMessage);
    }

    // all method in HttpClient call use SendAsync method internally so we are overriding that method here.
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.RequestUri != null && fakeServiceResponse.ContainsKey(request.RequestUri))
        {
            var fakeHttpResponseMessage = fakeServiceResponse[request.RequestUri];
            fakeHttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage = request;
            return Task.FromResult(fakeHttpResponseMessage);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            RequestMessage = request,
            Content = new StringContent("No matching fake found")
        });
    }
}
```

Now, let's set up some fake values for the test:

```
string fakeTenantId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

string fakeSecret = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

const string fakeScope = "fakeScope";

string fakeToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";
```

As we mentioned earlier, `AcquireTokenForClient` makes two calls for getting the token, so let's define the endpoint urls for both of those calls, which are required for faking the `HttpClient` through `FakeHttpResponseHandler`. Note that the endpoint may change if you are setting up the `IConfidentialClientApplication` differently than mentioned in this article.

```
string authEndpoint = Uri.EscapeDataString("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize");

string discoverEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com:443/common/discovery/instance?api-version=1.1&authorization_endpoint={authEndpoint}";

string tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
```

Now we have all the url's(keys) lets setup the response for each call.

```
HttpResponseMessage fakeDiscoverResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    RequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Empty),
    Content = new StringContent(
        "{\"tenant_discovery_endpoint\":\"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + 
        fakeTenantId 
        + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration\",\"api-version\":\"1.1\",\"metadata\":[{\"preferred_network\":\"login.microsoftonline.com\",\"preferred_cache\":\"login.windows.net\",\"aliases\":[\"login.microsoftonline.com\",\"login.windows.net\",\"login.microsoft.com\",\"sts.windows.net\"]},{\"preferred_network\":\"login.partner.microsoftonline.cn\",\"preferred_cache\":\"login.partner.microsoftonline.cn\",\"aliases\":[\"login.partner.microsoftonline.cn\",\"login.chinacloudapi.cn\"]},{\"preferred_network\":\"login.microsoftonline.de\",\"preferred_cache\":\"login.microsoftonline.de\",\"aliases\":[\"login.microsoftonline.de\"]},{\"preferred_network\":\"login.microsoftonline.us\",\"preferred_cache\":\"login.microsoftonline.us\",\"aliases\":[\"login.microsoftonline.us\",\"login.usgovcloudapi.net\"]},{\"preferred_network\":\"login-us.microsoftonline.com\",\"preferred_cache\":\"login-us.microsoftonline.com\",\"aliases\":[\"login-us.microsoftonline.com\"]}]}")
};
```

Note that we are setting the desired token in this response as `fakeToken`.

```
HttpResponseMessage fakeAuthResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    RequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, string.Empty),
    Content = new StringContent(
        "{\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":2588,\"ext_expires_in\":2588,\"access_token\":\"" + 
        fakeToken 
        + "\"}")
};
```

Now we have all the details. Let's start setting up the fakes for Discover and Token API calls in `FakeHttpResponseHandler`.

```
FakeHttpResponseHandler fakeAuthHandler = new FakeHttpResponseHandler();

fakeAuthHandler.AddFakeServiceResponse(new Uri(discoverEndpoint), fakeDiscoverResponseMessage);
fakeAuthHandler.AddFakeServiceResponse(new Uri(tokenEndpoint), fakeAuthResponseMessage);
```

Now we need to mock `IMsalHttpClientFactory` to return `HttpClient`, which uses `FakeHttpResponseHandler`, because we need this to be passed to `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` so that we can use our fake `HttpClient` implementation.

```
Mock<IMsalHttpClientFactory> msalHttpClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IMsalHttpClientFactory>();
msalHttpClientFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetHttpClient()).Returns(new HttpClient(fakeAuthHandler));
```

Finally, we need to setup the `IConfidentialClientApplication` with the `fakeTenantId`,`fakeSecret` and `msalHttpClientFactoryMock`.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication fakeConfidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(fakeTenantId)
            .WithClientSecret(fakeSecret)
            .WithHttpClientFactory(msalHttpClientFactoryMock.Object)
            .Build();
```

That's it; if we pass this `fakeConfidentialClientApplication` to the `IConfidentialClientApplication` of the `TokenService`, we will get the desired output. The full test method is below for reference.

```
public class TokenServiceTest
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetFakeTokenByMockingConfidentialClientApplicationAcquireTokenForClient()
    {
        string fakeTenantId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        string fakeSecret = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        string fakeToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";

        const string fakeScope = "fakeScope";

        string authEndpoint = Uri.EscapeDataString("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize");

        string discoverEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com:443/common/discovery/instance?api-version=1.1&authorization_endpoint={authEndpoint}";

        string tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";

        HttpResponseMessage fakeDiscoverResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            RequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Empty),
            Content = new StringContent(
                "{\"tenant_discovery_endpoint\":\"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + fakeTenantId + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration\",\"api-version\":\"1.1\",\"metadata\":[{\"preferred_network\":\"login.microsoftonline.com\",\"preferred_cache\":\"login.windows.net\",\"aliases\":[\"login.microsoftonline.com\",\"login.windows.net\",\"login.microsoft.com\",\"sts.windows.net\"]},{\"preferred_network\":\"login.partner.microsoftonline.cn\",\"preferred_cache\":\"login.partner.microsoftonline.cn\",\"aliases\":[\"login.partner.microsoftonline.cn\",\"login.chinacloudapi.cn\"]},{\"preferred_network\":\"login.microsoftonline.de\",\"preferred_cache\":\"login.microsoftonline.de\",\"aliases\":[\"login.microsoftonline.de\"]},{\"preferred_network\":\"login.microsoftonline.us\",\"preferred_cache\":\"login.microsoftonline.us\",\"aliases\":[\"login.microsoftonline.us\",\"login.usgovcloudapi.net\"]},{\"preferred_network\":\"login-us.microsoftonline.com\",\"preferred_cache\":\"login-us.microsoftonline.com\",\"aliases\":[\"login-us.microsoftonline.com\"]}]}")
        };

        HttpResponseMessage fakeAuthResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            RequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, string.Empty),
            Content = new StringContent(
                "{\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":2588,\"ext_expires_in\":2588,\"access_token\":\"" + fakeToken + "\"}")
        };

        FakeHttpResponseHandler fakeAuthHandler = new FakeHttpResponseHandler();

        fakeAuthHandler.AddFakeServiceResponse(new Uri(discoverEndpoint), fakeDiscoverResponseMessage);
        fakeAuthHandler.AddFakeServiceResponse(new Uri(tokenEndpoint), fakeAuthResponseMessage);

        Mock<IMsalHttpClientFactory> msalHttpClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IMsalHttpClientFactory>();
        msalHttpClientFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetHttpClient()).Returns(new HttpClient(fakeAuthHandler));

        IConfidentialClientApplication fakeConfidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(fakeTenantId)
            .WithClientSecret(fakeSecret).WithHttpClientFactory(msalHttpClientFactoryMock.Object).Build();

        var sut = new TokenService(fakeConfidentialClientApplication);

        var response = await sut.GetToken(new string[] { fakeScope });

        Assert.Equal(fakeToken, response);
    }
}
```

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thanks, I think this one is the best approach

Comment: code for mocking FakeHttpResponseHandler.
Mock<HttpMessageHandler> httpMessageHandlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
 httpMessageHandlerMock.Protected()
    .SetupSequence<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(fakeDiscoverResponseMessage)
    .ReturnsAsync(fakeAuthResponseMessage);

 Mock<IMsalHttpClientFactory> msalHttpClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IMsalHttpClientFactory>();
 msalHttpClientFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetHttpClient()).Returns(new HttpClient(httpMessageHandlerMock.Object));